How is "a" pronounced in the end of words in Provençal Occitan?
Is there any rule? For exemple "santa" is pronounced ['sãtə]. I think that in Nissard it is pronounced [a] but I'm not sure.
I would also like to know for Auvergnat and Gascon.

In Nissard it’s not at the end of the word. Reduction to schwa is common in Romance in unstressed final syllables, especially open ones, but in Nissard the final syllable is not only closed, but more importantly stressed.

So the shift to schwa only occures when the a is unstressed?

That’s by far the most common conditioning in all languages in the world, yes. Schwa is the most neutral, central vowel, and in weak, unstressed position, all vowels have a tendency all over the world to start moving towards neutrality. It’s much, much rarer for it to happen in stressed position.

Thank you! That helps me a lot! But isn't Provença [pɾuˈvɛnsə] then?

I don’t really know Provençal, but based on etymology and the forms found in the neighbouring Romance languages, I would imagine so, yes.

Thanks you a lot!

[at the of words, not in]

@Raggi_2009 Wikipedia says [pʁuˈvɛ̃ⁿso̞]

In Provençal, an unstressed final '-a' is pronounced like a light [ɔ] or [o̞] but is often closer to a schwa, possibly more with current speakers who have a French accent.
The Mistralian spelling uses O so the Provençal anthem is written La coupo santo while the Occitan traditional spelling is La copa santa: ['kupo̞ 's⁽ã⁾to̞].
That pronunciation of '-a' would be similar whatever the Provençal variant, including the Nissart although it is sometimes reported as [a] in that latter case.
The pronunciation of '-a' in other Occitan dialects is also generally [ɔ]/[o̞] except with the following variants that kept the [a] sound: Aranese, Southern Auvergnat, Pyrenean Béarnese, Donasanese (Catalan transition area), Montpellier and Nîmes sub-dialects, and Vivaro-Alpine.

And in auvergnat and gascon?

Answer updated.
